# moving tilemap with sprite?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to show my tile map portion where my sprite is generate and then move sprite map with sprite movement. How I can achieve this in cocos2dx. I try ccfollow but not get success.

```
_tileMap->runAction(CCFollow::actionWithTarget(_player));
```